# Variance of sample fourth moment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. standard normal variables. We assume we know that they are standardized and i.i.d., but we don't know the distribution. We want to estimate $M_4:=E[X^4_i]=3$. One possibility is to compute the sample fourth moment:

$$\hat{M}_4:=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^4$$

By the law of large numbers $\hat{M}_4$ will converge in probability to $M_4$. Another possible estimator for $M_4$ is

$$\hat{M}_{4}^{'}:=\frac{\hat{M}_4}{(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2)^2} $$

Simulations seem to indicate that $\hat{M}_{4}^{'}$ is more precise than $\hat{M}_4$, with a mean squared error smaller by a around $1/2$.

Are there theoretical reasons for this? Am looking for a formal calculation.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is $M_4'$ an estimator of $E[X_i^4]$? It looks like an estimator of $E[X_i^4]/E[X_i^2]^2$, which is different in general.

Comment: @Adam Correct. In my case I have $E[X_i^2]=1$.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you'd consider this a "theoretical reason", but this sort of makes sense – if you scale all the $X_i$ by a factor, the first estimator varies a lot, whereas the second one doesn't vary at all; so in a sense you've eliminated one direction along which variance is produced.

Comment: @joriki Not sure I understand the reasoning. The denominator should be very close to $1$, so intuitively scaling should not make that big of a difference.

Comment: @Alphie: Well, $M_4$ should also be close to $1$; but I doubt you'd be surprised that replacing it by $1$ in the estimator decreases the variance. How much is "that big of a difference"? What other effect are you comparing it to that you expect to make more of a difference?

Comment: @joriki I added details in the post to clarify. We assume we know that the $X_i$ are i.i.d. and standardized, but we don't know the distibution. We want to estimate $E[X_i^4]=3$. The MSE of the second estimator seems to be half the MSE of the first.

Comment: You've now introduced a contradiction into the post. The first sentence still says that these are standard normal variables, but the second one now says that you don't know the distribution. In any case, none of what I wrote above is affected by any of this as far as I can tell.

Comment: @joriki My reading of it is that the data generating process is normal IID, but only the IID part is known to the statistician performing the estimation.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Exactly thats what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling that the answer given a few days ago was too short: here is a detailed proof...

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n,\ldots$iid with law $N(0,1)$ and
$$M_2(n)=\frac{1}{n}(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2),\ M_4(n)=\frac{1}{n}(X_1^4+\cdots+X_n^4).$$ We compute the variance of  $M'_4(n)=M_4(n)/(M_2(n))^2.$ To this end recall the definition of a Dirichlet distribution $\mathcal{D}(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_N)$ where $a_0,\ldots,a_N>0.$ We say that $(U_0,U_1,\cdots,U_N)\sim \mathcal{D}(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_N)$ if $U_0,\ldots,U_N>0$ and $U_0+\cdots+U_N=1$ and if the density  $(U_1,\ldots,U_N)$ is
$$C(1-u_1-\ldots-u_N)^{a_0-1}u_1^{a_1-1}\ldots u_N^{a_N-1}$$
with $$\frac{1}{C}=B(a_0,\ldots,a_N)=\frac{\Gamma(a_0)\ldots \Gamma(a_N)}{\Gamma(a_0+\cdots+a_N)}.$$ Remember that if $Y_0,\ldots,Y_N$ are independent with respective densities on $(0,\infty)$ equal to   $b(by_i)^{a_i-1}e^{-by_i}/\Gamma(a_i)$ then
$$ (U_0,\ldots,U_N)=\frac{(Y_0,\ldots,Y_N)}{Y_0+\cdots+Y_N}\sim \mathcal{D}(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_N).\ \ (*)$$ This is a classical fact and we skip its proof. From (*) we obtain that $$(U_0+\cdots+U_k,U_{k+1},\ldots,U_N)\sim \mathcal{D}(a_0+a_1,+\cdots+a_k,a_{k+1},\ldots, a_N)\ (**).$$
We apply this $Y_i=X_i^2$ which has a chisquare distribution, namely a gamma law with $b=2$ et $a_i=1/2.$ Therefore  if $U_i=X_i^2/nM_2(n)$
alors $$M'_4(n)=n(U_1^2+\cdots+U_n^2)$$ since $(U_1,\ldots,U_n)\sim \mathcal{D}(1/2,\ldots,1/2).$ From (**) we have
$$(U_1,U_2+\cdots+U_n)\sim \mathcal{D}(1/2,(n-1)/2),\ (U_1,U_2, U_3+\cdots+U_n)\sim \mathcal{D}(1/2,1/2,(n-2)/2.\ (***).$$

Now we compute
$$\mathbb{E}(M'_4(n))=n^2\mathbb{E}(U_1^2)=n^2\frac{B(2+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{n-1}{2})}{B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2})}=\frac{3n}{n+2}$$
The evaluation of  $\mathbb{E}((M'_4(n))^2)$ is more involved and needs the values of  $\mathbb{E}(U_1^4)$ and of $\mathbb{E}(U_1^2U_2^2)$, still using(***).

$$\mathbb{E}(U_1^4)=\frac{B(4+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{n-1}{2})}{B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2})}=\frac{\Gamma(4+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}\times \frac{\Gamma(4+\frac{n-1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})}=\frac{7\times 5\times 3}{(n+6)(n+4)(n+2)n}$$

$$\mathbb{E}(U_1^2U_2^2)=\frac{B(2+\frac{1}{2}, 2+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{n-2}{2})}{B(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{n-2}{2})}=\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{5}{2})}{\Gamma^2(\frac{1}{2})}\times \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+4)}=\frac{9}{(n+6)(n+4)(n+2)n}$$ As a consequence

$$\mathbb{E}((M'_4(n))^2)=n^2[n\mathbb{E}(U_1^4)+n(n-1)\mathbb{E}(U_1^2U_2^2)]=\frac{3n^2(3n+32)}{(n+6)(n+4)(n+2)}$$

$$\sigma^2(M'_4(n))=\mathbb{E}((M'_4(n))^2)-(\mathbb{E}(M'_4(n)))^2=\frac{24n^2(n-1)}{(n+6)(n+4)(n+2)^2}\sim _{n\to \infty}\frac{24}{n}.$$

Comment: I do not understand why this answer was deleted, while it offers an exact solution to a not-so-easy problem.

Answer (score 0):

So your sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ has an unknown distribution but you know that the mean and the variance of this distribution are $0$ and $1$. You would like to decide whether or not $E(X_i^4)=3$ (if not, you reject Gaussianity). I understand that you want to compute the variances of $M_4$ and $M'_4$. This is clearly impossible if you do not know the distribution. But if you assume that $X_i\sim N(0,1)$ the computation of these two variances becomes  a reasonable problem. The trick for performing the calculations is to consider $Y_i=X_i^2$ and $U_i=Y_i/(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n).$ With this notation $(U_1,\ldots,U_n)$ has a Dirichlet distribution with parameters $(1/2,\ldots,1/2).$ For instance $$E(M'_4)=nE(U_1^2+\cdots+U_n^2)=n^2E(U_1^2)=\frac{3n}{n+2}$$
and $E((M'_4)^2)=n^2E[(U_1^2+\cdots+U_n^2)^2].$

Since the distribution of $U_1^2$ is Beta$(1/2,(n-1)/2)$
and since the joint density of $(U_1,U_2)$ is $u_1^{-1/2}u_2^{-1/2}(1-u_1-u_2)^{(n-4)/2}$ the calculation of $E((M'_4)^2)$ is possible: the price is a simple double integral. I have not completed the calculations, but you have raised an interesting problem.

Comment: The variance of $M'_4$ is $$\frac{24n^2(n-1)}{(n+2)^2(n+4)(n+6)}\sim_{n\to \infty} \frac{24}{n}$$ and the variance of $M_4$ is $\frac{87}{2n}.$

Comment: Alfie's simulations were suggesting a ratio of 1/2 of the two variances. The exact asymptotic value is 48/87=0.55...Are your simulations coherent with that value?